# Docker images on different docker versions

Tags: docker

I have a docker installation of version 1.12.0 on my development server.

I would like to test my image on a different server (testing) that is a replica of the production environment.

The highest version of Docker I could install is 1.7.0.

To move the image I use the commands:

```
$ docker save -o my-image-file.tar my-image
```

And to import on the test server:

```
$ docker load -i my-image-file.tar
```

And worked as I had:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
my-image      0.0.1-alpha.0       4f73652ffdd1        12 days ago         813.4 MB
```

But when I try to run it, I got the following issue:

```
$ docker run --rm -t my-image:0.0.1-alpha.0
```

> Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 1388707e60edd19170f3064c548da7bf72f045a85498854339e3447c2ab97e98: device or resource busy

If I run the *docker ps*:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

And:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d96a19b4dcc0        my-image:0.0.1-alpha.0   "npm start"         6 seconds ago                                               focused_goldstine
```

Is this an issue between the 2 different docker versions?

Can I fix it without use the same docker version?

**UPDATE**

I set up the internet connection and try to launch a container downloaded from the docker.io registry.

It pull the image, but cannot run the container.

Same error.

Comment: Can you try `umount /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/1388707e60edd19170f3064c548da7bf72f045a85498854339e3447c2ab97e98` and restart the container

Comment: I did, but it was not mounted and when I run the container again had the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.7 is a pretty old version. In 1.8.3 there was a security patch that made some changes. You can read about it in [the Docker blog](https://blog.docker.com/2015/10/security-release-docker-1-8-3-1-6-2-cs7/). You may be just using incompatible versions.

Comment: You were right, the issue was some sort of compatibility, but I could solve it installing just docker v1.7.1. The reason is I'm stick on CentOS v6 and kernel 2.6.x. This is an equivalent of production REDHAT server that could not be touched. Thanks a lot!